# In QML can a dynamic object component be created in another file/page?

Tags: qt, qml, components

I am creating dynamic questions, where questions are to be sorted by type and arranged onto specific pages. Can the parent in this sample be expanded to include page or qrc file information?

```
function createSpriteObjects() {
    component = Qt.createComponent("Sprite.qml");
    sprite = component.createObject(appWindow, {x: 100, y: 100});
```

I want the "appWindow" parent to include page information something like:

```js
// send this question to question page1 and set appWindow as parent
var location = "qrc:/pages/Question_type_page1.qml"+appWindow;  //an existing page

// and then sprite becomes
sprite = component.createObject(location, {x: 100, y: 100});
```

Results thus far are just type errors on anchors and no output to any page

Comment: As for me I understand absolutely nothing. Can you please clarify the question? Maybe some working code that we can test?

Comment: I am sorry I was not clear.  I used the example code to keep it simple.  I have a list of questions.  There are 3 types of questions.  There are 3 question pages.  I iterate through each question, check its type, create the component, add options, then for question type 1 I want to send it to Question_type_page1.  How can I create my object and set its parent as page 1 and its column?  In my example code I am simply adding a var called "location" which I prepend to the parent input as arg1 of the createObject function but that is wrong.  How do I define "page" as part of the parent?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have not found an exact answer but I have established a work around.  Instead of trying to send each question to its own ".qml" page I created the question pages within my original window and dynamically sort and create each question object on these pages.  Then I just use the visible: attribute within 'Page' to make each page visible over top of the main window.  This way all pages are maintained within the focus of the original window.